# Type Mismatch Using ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

Code below is supposed to hide all columns where any of its cells contain a certain value. If I directly specify a search Range, it works. However, if I use "ActiveSheet.UsedRange", it throws a type mismatch error. What is going on?

```
Sub HideColumn()

    Dim MySel As Range
    
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.Value = "X123" Then
            If MySel Is Nothing Then
                Set MySel = cell
            Else
                Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    MySel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Logically, you should use `If not MySel is nothing then MySel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True`. To avoid an error in case of no any match. Is there any workbook open? If yes, try declaring and qualifying all used variables/objects: `Dim cell as Range` and `For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.cells`. Do you run the code in Excel, or like an automation from another application?

Comment: I run it in Excel. Had already tried all of that. VBasic2008's answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hide Columns of Cells Equal To a String

- If a cell contains an error value, the line `If cell.Value = "X123" Then` will fail with a *Type mismatch* error. In the following code, this is handled by converting the cell value to a string with `CStr(cell.Value)`. Another way would be to add an outer (preceding) *If* statement `If Not IsError(cell) Then`.
- `Option Explicit` would have warned you that the `cell` variable is not declared forcing you to do `Dim cell As Range`. Why don't you use it?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideColumns()

    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Dim crg As Range, cell As Range, urg As Range
    
    For Each crg In rg.Columns
        For Each cell In crg.Cells
            If StrComp(CStr(cell.Value), "X123", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = cell
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
                End If
                Exit For ' match in column found; no need to loop anymore
            End If
        Next cell
    Next crg
    
    rg.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide all columns
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then urg.EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide matching

End Sub
```